# Some question about RIA Services

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I've some questions regarding the RIA Services in a Silverlight business application.

1. In most samples the business logic is really simple. normally you would CRUD an entity. But what if there were a work flow that should meet?
2. Assume we have a parent entity which on insert it should contain some other entities as child items.
   Should I write a method that accept the child items as its parameter or if the client (SL app) adds them to the Items collection of the parent entity it would do the trick and on the InsertParentEntity method I can get them?
3. Is there any limits to sending objects on each call to an operation like in WCF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's definitely a standard RIA pattern to add business logic to your CRUD methods. Feel free to call into workflow or pretty much anything else.
2. If you add a parent on the client and add some children to it's EntityCollection, when you submit all the entities will show up on the server. An Insert method will get called for each one (for instance, 1 InsertParent and 3 InsertChild).
3. Yes, the limit and the solution are the same as in WCF.